# Removing nearby points R

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to remove spatially correlated points from a point dataset. I need to remove points from the original dataset so that all points in the output are no closer that 'x' meters. I have no preference as to how these points are chosen.

I have found a variety of methods for calculating the distances between points, but I am unsure of how to use them to achieve the end goal.

Question 1: Does this functionality exist within one of the many spatial analysis packages? I have been unable to find anything, but I could be missing the proper search terms.

If not,

Question 2: Would it be practical to use the following procedure (up to 500k points to select from)?

1. Randomly select one point from the original dataset
2. Randomly select another point, check whether it is within "x" meters of the first,
   output if no, skip if yes
3. Iterate this process adding one point at a time, checking distance
   with the accumulated points in the output dataset.

I'm not necessarily asking for help with the code at this point (though I would definitely need it), rather trying to gauge what is available and/or a practical way to achieve the goal.

Comment: I gave some pointers to someone who asked this same question about a month ago, and it looks like they ran with my suggestion and posted a solution of their own. I can't vouch for the solution (haven't tried it myself), but [here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22051141/980833).

Comment: Thanks Josh, I came across this right when you replied. Hopefully I can get it working as well, I appreciate the reply.

Comment: No problem. Do see the comment that I just left on the accepted answer to that question, though, before applying it to your own data.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own little program to achieve this, mostly because I don't know enough background to adapt the code recommended by Josh, though I am fully confident it would be possible.

I know this is definitely not the most efficient, clean, or probably recommended way of solving the problem, but it seems to work for me.

Example: starting with a dataframe 'aa' with two data columns 'a' and 'b', coordinates 'easting' and 'northing', and a grouping variable 'Z'

ProxFiltered keeps points separated by distances greater than 1 within each level of Z

```
aa <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),easting=rnorm(100),northing=rnorm(100),Z=rep(1:4, each=25))
aa <- aa[sample(nrow(aa)),]
split.aa<-split(aa, aa$Z)

ProxFiltered<-aa[0,]
for (j in 1:4){
  out<- split.aa[[j]][1,]
  for(i in 2:nrow(split.aa[[j]])){
    pts<- as.matrix(out[,3:4])
    pt<-  as.numeric(split.aa[[j]][i,3:4])
    dists<- spDistsN1(pts, pt, longlat = FALSE)
    exceed<- any(dists<1)
    if (exceed==FALSE){
      out<-rbind(out, split.aa[[j]][i,])
    }
  }
  ProxFiltered<-rbind(out, ProxFiltered)}
```

For each element for list 'split.aa', the first row (point) is selected.

The next point is selected and the distance to the first is calculated.

If the distance is greater than the threshold (in this case 1), then the point is added to the filtered data.

The process is iterated one point at a time, measuring the distance from each new point to all those already in the filtered data, only adding it to the filtered data if none of those distances are less than the threshold.

This can be verified by checking the distances between all points at one level of Z

```
dist(subset(ProxFiltered,Z==1))
```

As opposed to the original data

```
dist(subset(aa,Z==1))
```